# How to print a html page ignore the responsive view css?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to print a html page, the html page is responsive. The format printed is just fine when view in desktop. But, the problem here is when using mobile, the printed format will be different from the printed version using desktop. The content is enlarged. How can i make the format printed from mobile same as desktop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media print` in your CSS and make sure query applied in the correct place in your CSS file.
Example:

```
@media print
   {
      p.bodyText {font-family:Georgia, times, serif;}
   }
```

Or If you are defining your style sheet in a separate file, then you can also use the media attribute when linking to an external style sheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="mystyle.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add desktop media query for printing. something like this

```
@media print and (min-width: 1024px) {
}
```

Comment: actually i want to print the format same as desktop during using mobile. In my case, when i am resizing the browser window, then the printing format also will be affected. The content will look bigger as well.